# Web login using python or wget (JavaScript Challenge/response)

Tags: python, authentication, curl, scrapy, wget

i am newbie with web scrapy and login. I need to login to an UPS to read information via Python or wget not matter which.

I tried to do it with wget:

```
wget --no-check-certificate --keep-session-cookies --post-data 
'Username=admin&Password=admin' https://192.168.50.2/delta/login
```

But always get a web page with the error "Challenge not found"

Do you know any way to gets login in using challenge+response?

Here are the login page source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<!-- saved from url=(0035)https://192.168.50.2/home.asp -->
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Web Server Login</title>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9,8,7,6,5">

<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="-1">
<!--<base target="_top">--><base href="." target="_top">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./Web Server Login_files/template.css" type="text/css">
<script language="javascript" src="./Web Server Login_files/js.js.download"></script><script data-dapp-detection="">
(function() {
  let alreadyInsertedMetaTag = false

  function __insertDappDetected() {
    if (!alreadyInsertedMetaTag) {
      const meta = document.createElement('meta')
      meta.name = 'dapp-detected'
      document.head.appendChild(meta)
      alreadyInsertedMetaTag = true
    }
  }

  if (window.hasOwnProperty('web3')) {
    // Note a closure can't be used for this var because some sites like
    // www.wnyc.org do a second script execution via eval for some reason.
    window.__disableDappDetectionInsertion = true
    // Likely oldWeb3 is undefined and it has a property only because
    // we defined it. Some sites like wnyc.org are evaling all scripts
    // that exist again, so this is protection against multiple calls.
    if (window.web3 === undefined) {
      return
    }
    __insertDappDetected()
  } else {
    var oldWeb3 = window.web3
    Object.defineProperty(window, 'web3', {
      configurable: true,
      set: function (val) {
        if (!window.__disableDappDetectionInsertion)
          __insertDappDetected()
        oldWeb3 = val
      },
      get: function () {
        if (!window.__disableDappDetectionInsertion)
          __insertDappDetected()
        return oldWeb3
      }
    })
  }
})()</script><script type="text/javascript" src="./Web Server Login_files/jquery-1.4.4.pack.js.download"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="./Web Server Login_files/md5.js.download"></script>
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--
function calcResponse() {
str = document.login.Username.value +
document.login.Password.value +
document.login.Challenge.value;
document.login.Response.value = hex_md5(str);
if(1)
    document.login.Password.value = "";
document.login.Challenge.value = "";
}
var logoix = "1";
var lang_support = "1111000000000000";
var odmtag = "0";

function Initialize(flag_Submit)
{
    document.login.Username.focus();
    if(flag_Submit) {
        document.login.Submitbtn.click();
    }
    chklogo(logoix,'dlogos')
    if(odmtag == "0")
    {
        document.getElementById('footnote').style.display="block"
        document.getElementById('tabtitle').className="tabtl"
        document.getElementById('logintitle').className="logintl"
    }
}
--></script>
</head>

<body style="display: block;" onload="pageload();loadjs(&#39;/java/langs.js&#39;);setTimeout(&#39;Initialize()&#39;,10);">
<div style="display:none" id="currlang">0</div>
<form name="login" action="https://192.168.50.2/delta/login" method="post">
    <center>
    <div id="dslogin">
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <div class="sidebox">
        <h3>&nbsp;</h3>
        <div class="sb">
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="480">
                <tbody><tr><th colspan="3" id="tabtitle" class="tabtl"><div id="logintitle" class="logintl">UPSentry 2012</div></th></tr>
                <tr><td colspan="3" style="padding-right:-6px;" valign="top">
                    <table cellpadding="8" cellspacing="8" border="0" height="100%" width="100%" class="loginfield">
                    <tbody><tr><td colspan="2"><img src="./Web Server Login_files/sp.gif" width="1" height="3"></td></tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="logintext"><span id="#2">User Name</span> : </td>
                        <td align="left"><input type="text" name="Username" value="" size="24" maxlength="32" style="font-size: 12px; background-image: url(&quot;data:image/png;base64,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&quot;); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-attachment: scroll; background-size: 16px 18px; background-position: 98% 50%;" autocomplete="off"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="logintext"><span id="#3">Password</span> : </td>
                        <td align="left"><input type="password" name="Password" value="" size="24" maxlength="32" style="font-size: 12px; background-image: url(&quot;data:image/png;base64,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&quot;); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-attachment: scroll; background-size: 16px 18px; background-position: 98% 50%;" autocomplete="off"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td align="left"><input class="okbutn" onclick="calcResponse()" id="#4" type="Submit" name="Submitbtn" value="      OK      "></td></tr>
                    </tbody></table>
                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" class="logindevip"><span id="#5">Site IP</span>: 192.168.50.2</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody></table>
        </div>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="Challenge" value="f1e0....">
        <input type="hidden" name="Response" value="">
        <div id="footnote" style="display: block;">
            <span id="#6">Copyright ©, All rights reserved.</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    </center>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Regards!

Comment: What have you tried with Scrapy?

Comment: Hi @Gallaecio, yes, i have tried with scrapy also without lucky. Is i said in my previous post, i am very newbie with scrapy, hehe.